# Nextjs - Inject ContextProvider if running in client side

Tags: reactjs, websocket, next.js

How do I ensure that my contextprovider will only run on client side.

I have two providers used in `_app.tsx` namely ChakraProvider (for chakra-ui) and SocketProvider (for websocket).

```
export default function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
  return (
    <ChakraProvider>
      <SocketProvider wsUrl={'ws://localhost:4000/socket'}>
        <Component {...pageProps} />
      </SocketProvider>
    </ChakraProvider>
  );
}
```

When I try to access the page, it says:

```
Server Error

TypeError: Cannot read property 'WebSocket' of undefined
```

but when I try it on client side, SocketProvider works fine and there are no errors being thrown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this `checkWindow` function to detect client side:

```
export default () => typeof window !== 'undefined';
```

Resource: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/5354#issuecomment-520305040

Update:

Good example of using socket with Next.js: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/442fbfaa4d4e8205cf10c7e5d27b8f51b7a4bdc6/examples/with-socket.io